# VOIP - how to see which number is called

Tags: voip, sip

I want to use VOIP telephone, but want to have a few telephone numbers which will be answered by one person. Problem is I want to see to which number caller is calling.
For example:
I have a numbers X, Y and Z. Caller is calling on number X, so I want to see on my screen (or telephone screen) a name that I assigned to this number.
I just add that it can be up to 15-20 numbers.

The opereator I'm considering is [FCN](http://www.fcn.pl/) and as I know they are using SIP protocol.
They told me this is impossible, but I just want to know is it only that they don't know how to do it.

Is there some software/telephone that can show me to which number someone is calling?

Answer (score 1):

This is far from impossible, but it is very dependent on what PBX (and phone) you use.

SIP is a great protocol, but if you are using their SIP service and a telephone that connects directly, you are pretty much reliant on either the features of their service or your phone.

For example, most business-class (e.g. not cheap, home ones) SIP phones should be able to tell you what trunk/connection the call came in on.

Alternatively, you can use a PBX such as [TrixBox](http://www.trixbox.org/) where you can set up all your incoming SIP trunks and set very flexible rules.

I recently set up a Trixbox system for a client that is similar to what you want - HE has four numbers and a [Snom](http://www.snom.com/en/home/) phone, I have it so that he has 4 different numbers and the Trixbox manages different voicemail entries for each and the phone itself both displays the incoming number and has a different ring for each!